# WSO2IS Illegal access attempt WARNING

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have deployed two WSO2IS servers in cluster, the deployment seems to be working fine as the answer to the requests made are consitents and all the policy stuff is working.

But I get the same error for every request I make, which Im unable to find out the real meaning, if this is a normal behaviour or on the contrary, there is something wrong Im missing.

As you can see, first I get the "WARNING: Illegal acces attempt.." followed by a successful login with the default user (ADmin)...

[2014-04-14 12:57:36,293]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  Illegal access attempt at [2014-04-14 12:57:36,0292]
 from IP address 10.6.10.11 while trying to authenticate access to service EntitlementService
[2014-04-14 12:57:36,423]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-04-14 12:5
7:36,423+0200]

I would appreciate your help,

Thanks in advance,

Jorge.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing the "EntitlementService" which is an admin service. Therefore you need to authenticate to access this service. Basically you need to send user/password in basic authentication header, In basic authentication, client normally sends the basic headers, when  server gives an unauthorized responses. This is why,  you would see above `Illegal access attempt` log in every time and after client sends the header, user would be authenticated. But you can avoid it by using `Preemptive Authentication` mode with basic authentication.  If you are using a Httpclient library to send the request, you can enable it. Please refer [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html)

Comment: Hello Asela, Thank you very much for your answer.                  Using Premptive Authentication solved the problem. Im using a C# library, I just nedeed to put the preauthenticate property of the request to True, and the warning disappeared.     `EntitlementService service = new EntitlementService();
CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(USER, PASSWORD);
credCache.Add(new Uri(service.Url), "Basic", netCred);
service.Credentials = credCache;          
service.PreAuthenticate = true;'